# Why the point is missing after the number in this enumerate list?

Tags: lists, punctuation, enumerate, templates

I've always used latex for writing papers and documents but I'm not really expert of templates and styles.

Currently I'm working on a document and I'm using a template that was provided by a colleague. Unfortunately when I use `\begin{enumerate}` the generated list contains numbers that are not followed by points (e.g. I see `1` instead of `1.`).

I tried to look in the `cls` file and I found the following code, however I wasn't able to fix it.

```
%% Redefine enumerate environment for closer spacing
\renewenvironment{enumerate}%
{\begin{list}{\arabic{enumi}}%
      {\setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5em}%
       \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%
       \setlength{\topsep}{-\parskip}%%
       \usecounter{enumi}}%
 }{\end{list}}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the above question we only need to put a dot after `\arabic{enumi}`

```
%% Redefine enumerate environment for closer spacing
\renewenvironment{enumerate}%
{\begin{list}{\arabic{enumi}.}% <------ dot here
      {\setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5em}%
       \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%
       \setlength{\topsep}{-\parskip}%%
       \usecounter{enumi}}%
 }{\end{list}}
```

Using the `enumitem` package one could write:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic{*}.,topsep=-\parskip,itemsep=-\parsep,leftmargin=2.5em]
\item 
\end{enumerate}
```

Which also yields the same result.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument of the `list` environment gives an indication of the printed counter. [`source2e`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf) (p 273) lists the definition as:

```
\list{<LABEL>}{<COMMANDS>} ... \endlist
```

where `<LABEL>` is set to `\@itemlabel` - the printed counter at every `\item`. Modifying this to `\arabic{enumi}.` inserts the period after the number.

You can also obtain the same result using the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Redefine enumerate environment for closer spacing
\renewenvironment{enumerate}%
{\begin{list}{\arabic{enumi}.}%
      {\setlength{\leftmargin}{2.5em}%
       \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%
       \setlength{\topsep}{-\parskip}%%
       \usecounter{enumi}}%
 }{\end{list}}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item
  \item An item
  \item An item
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\noindent\usebox{\mybox}% Original

\bigskip

% With enumitem
\begin{enumerate}[topsep=-\parskip,itemsep=-\parsep,leftmargin=2.5em,label=\arabic*.]
  \item An item
  \item An item
  \item An item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The advantage with the latter, of course, is the flexibility to manage lists locally (or globally) in a consistent yet versatile way.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer! I selected azetina's one because it was the first!